# Relative path for project sdk in intellij idea

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Is there a way to set the project sdk for an intellij idea Python project to a relative path? I'd like to set the project sdk to a virtual environment that I include in the repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not. If you look in the `{projectRoot}/.idea/misc.xml` settings file, you will see that the project's SDK (named `project-jdk` for historical reasons) setting is referenced by name:

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" default="false" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="My Python SDK" project-jdk-type="Python SDK">
```

That name is the (unique) name of an SDK stored in the system wide `{ideaSettings}/config/options/jdk.table.xml` file (again named such for historical reasons). That file lists all SDKs defined in IntelliJ IDEA. So there is no way to define a project relative SDK.

I recommend you [open a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) to allow this. For most SDKs having a project specific definition does not make a lot of sense. But for Python Virtual Environments, I think it does.

The only **workaround** would be to have all developers create a project uniquely named Python SDK that points to the SDK within the project.

There is the *Path Variables* feature in IntelliJ IDEA. When saving path information in configuration files, IntelliJ IDEA will substitute a variable name (i.e. placeholder) for any items that are inside a defined path variable. However, that has more relevance for path settings stored in the project's configuration.  For example, it would allow a library setting to "point to" `$GLOBAL_JAVA_LIBS$/apache-commons-lang3.jar`. Then each developer could locate the global java libs directory where ever they wanted on their system and then just define the `GLOBAL_JAVA_LIBS` path variable to point to it. You can do this with your python SDK. But in the end, while the system specific `{ideaSettings}/config/options/jdk.table.xml` would have the variable placeholder in it, that would not be of much use since the developers would still need to define the Python SDK so it is in the `jdk.table.xml`. And since that is not under version control. It makes little sense to have a path placeholder.